# select from subquery select where condition throws error

Tags: sql

I have the below query where I am selecting from another subquery with where condition

```
if not exists
 (select @DocTaxID from (select  bundlechecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID, documentchecklist.Doc_Checklist_TXN_ID, documentchecklist.Doc_Type_Name from ecm.bundle_checklist_txn bundlechecklist
                    left outer join [ECM].[Document_Checklist_TXN] documentchecklist on documentchecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID = bundlechecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID
                    where bundlechecklist.originating_tran_id = "AMD" 
                    and bundle_name = 'Line') 
                    where @DocTaxID is not null )

    begin
         insert into [ECM].[Document_Checklist_TXN]
            (bundle_txn_id, document_action_rule_id, action_rule_name, doc_type_name, cp_document_name, document_id, doc_status_code)
         values
            (1, 17, 'A', 'DEv', 'Dec', 12, 'Pend')

    end
```

DocTaxID  is integer field.
And the error I am getting is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is because you aren't aliasing your sub-query: `... and bundle_name 'Line') As A Where @DocTaxId ...`  *however*, your query doesn't really make any sense.  The entire sub-query is ignored by the `WHERE @DocTaxID IS NOT NULL` segment.  Not to mention, the two variables aren't even used anywhere else in the snippet.  *Can you please explain what you're trying to do with the query?*

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Comment: yes its SQL server. sorry about that

Comment: bundlechecklist.originating_tran_id = 'AMD'   + give an alias to your subselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table alias:

```
select @DocTaxID
from (select bundlechecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID, documentchecklist.Doc_Checklist_TXN_ID, documentchecklist.Doc_Type_Name
      from ecm.bundle_checklist_txn bundlechecklist left outer join
           [ECM].[Document_Checklist_TXN] documentchecklist
           on documentchecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID = bundlechecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID
      where bundlechecklist.originating_tran_id = 'AMD' and bundle_name = 'Line'
     ) d
-------^
where @DocTaxID is not null ;
```

Somehow, I think there is a much simpler way to express this logic, but off-hand, it is not clear exactly what it is doing.